# PowerShell/WPF - зависает скрипт при получении Warning

Tags: powershell

Пытаюсь написать PowerShell скрипт с GUI. В качестве GUI использую WPF. После запуска скрипта отображается UI с полями для ввода имени компьютера (IP) и порта. При нажатии на кнопку Start выполняется Test-NetConnection ([средство для тестирования TCP портов](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection?view=win10-ps)), результаты выполнения я вывожу в файл или UI приложения. Проблема в следующем, если для тестирования указать открытый порт, то всё работает хорошо (не считая того, что пока Test-NetConnection не выполнится, UI приложения намертво зависает) Test-NetConnection отрабатывает. Но если я указываю закрытый порт, то я получаю Warning:

```
WARNING: TCP connect to (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx : 80) failed
```

После получения этого сообщения UI зависает совсем и в консоль больше ничего не выводится! Такое ощущение, что Test-NetConnection не может завершиться или я не получаю ошибку.

В процесске работы Test-NetConnection такие варнинги это норма, но они не приводят к зависанию скрипта без UI.

Cокращённый кусок кода, дабы не перегружать текст. Но смысл один, при наступлении события click выполняется Test-NetConnection, из -ComputerName берётся имя или IP, а из -Port соответственно порт, который необходимо проверить.

```
$StartButton.add_click({
   $out = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -Port xxx
   Write-Host $out
})
```

Я пробовал варианты запуска с дополнительными параметрами, например:

```
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -Port xxx -WarningAction Continue
```

Но это не помогло.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как диагностировать или исправить ошибку? Куда смотреть? Может кто использовал Test-NetConnection в приложениях с UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моём сценарии помог дополнительный параметр **-InformationLevel**, если его использовать со значением **Quiet**, то Test-NetConnection возвращает краткую сводку о успешности выполнения в формате true/false. Такой ответ не вызывает зависания UI.
Пример:

```
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -Port xxx -InformationLevel Quiet
```